# How do I check if a user has inputed a certain word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable with the value of input("") and I want it to check if the input has a certain word in it.

Code:

```
print("John: Hello!")

print('')

talkingToJohn = ''

while talkingToJohn != "Bye":
    talkingToJohn = input("")
```

Comment: You *do* get the input, you just do nothing but loop right away with it.

Comment: What possibilites have you tried?

Comment: If you type "Bye" when prompted, what happens?

Answer (score 5):

The following code should do the work:

```
print("John: Hello!")

talkingToJohn = ''
while not "bye" in talkingToJohn:
    talkingToJohn = input().lower()

    if "how old" in talkingToJohn:
         printMyAge()
    elif "where" in talkingToJohn:
         askLocation(talkingToJogn)
```

It'll loop while the user doesn't enter "bye" (case-insensitive here)

**EDIT:** If you want to manage question from the user you have to make a system which will parse the user input. Not quite easy (Cleverbot and co. aren't *that* simple to program...), but I gave you a simple first method here. Each method (`printMyAge`, `askLocation`) should returns text to the user, by printing something.

Comment: That is not really what I want to do. Here is what I want to do: If the user enter's something like "How are you today?" I want an if statement to see if the string that the user inputed contain's the word "How"

Comment: See my updated anwser.

Comment: @Noah In the future, you need to make the question state what you want.  There is no way for someone to give a good response if you don't list the requirements.   This includes example.s

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
>>> message = input(':')
:Hello World!
>>> if 'Hello' in message: print(True)
...
True
>>> message = input(':')
:hEllO wOrLd!
>>> if 'hello' in message.lower(): print(True)
...
True
>>>
```

Comment: @Noah - No problem.  Don't forget to accept an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to keep SO clean and organized.

Answer (score 2):

Here i am checking each word in the string to see if it is `Bye`.

```
talkingToJohn = raw_input()
talkingToJohn = talkingToJohn.split(" ")
for a in talkingToJohn:
    if a == "Bye":
        print "talkingToJohn conatins Bye"
```